# Determinant of square matrix created from non square ones?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Say I have 3 matrices A, B, C where A is 2x3 C is 3x3, B is 3x2. I have large amounts of information about all 3, I can get the determinant of C, its eigenvalues... etc.

Is there a way for me to describe the determinant of ABC in terms of properties of A, B and C?

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-Binet_formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula)

Comment: This is very helpful but I am not sure how to deal with the square matrix in between